# Problems with dialogs in swing

Tags: java, swing, resize, jdialog

When I create a new dialog using the swing and set **setResizable(false)** the icon on the title bar in the left corner is disapear, can somebody help me to solve this issue, I'm using jdk 1.5(required by project)???

Answer (score 1):

I remembered something about this from years ago and then I found [How can I set a icon image on JDialog's title bar?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=88691). Hopefully this steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Can you revise your question to say what you have done, putting the code in the comment makes it unreadable.

Comment: The thing which I done - create dummy frame, set the icon to the title bar and then set this frame as parent for dialog, did not help ((